# Profiles: parser extension?

Tags: hl7-fhir

we are needing to extend some FHIR resource for certain internal needs in our platform. We have already seen how to define the profiles extension like formal and structure description.

But, we have a doubt about parsers and profiles, is it necessary to modify parsers for new Profiles, or parsers are implemented for following of the formal description in the profile?

thanks in advance
  Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to modify the parsers; all the object models, parsers, servers and tools can handle all resources, however they are profiled (all extensions have the same schema, so they can all support whatever extensions there are)

Comment: Ok. I have understood it for parsers analyzing them in java implementation. But i suppose that if i extend a resource then i also should extend the model class with new methods (like for example with a new attribute) for after usage on client or server. is there some tools or java mechanisms for this or is it necessary to extend manually java classes ?  do you have some link to a fhir java client and server samples using extensions? Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: well, you could certainly add getters and setters to give a more direct access to the extensionm sure. And in fact, it's my intent to get around to extending the Java generator to do exactly this. However there's a challenge associated with this: when would you invoke this modified class?

Comment: Sorry Grahame, I am not sure i have understood the question or challenge in you last comment. we are thinking to create java classes which we will use in client and server, specifically for management and persistence. or do you mean how can it be implemented the generator?

Comment: well, if every use you have for a resource type has the extension, then, sure it works to just modify the base class. But what different instances of a resource are extended differently?